# Concat and uglify multiple parts of a function into one file with grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, split, gruntjs

So I have a node project with a javascript file that contains a **huge** function that has alot of code. I was wondering if I could breakup this standard javascript function, into seperate functions and have grunt "compile them" into 1 function in 1 file. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is completely posible... There are various ways of doing it..

**With grunt:** Try this [contrib module](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat). It is very easy to use and all the documentation is detailed in the link.

**Without grunt:** On the other hand if you want to try something without grunt you could try the [selectizer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/selectizer) module. If it fits your needs I think that this is a much better option given that you can arrenge your dependecies explicitly using the requireJs syntax and then compile all the modules into one single clean file. That makes your code easier to maintain in the mid-term/long-term. Also you could select which modules to build and which not, so in the final build there are going to be only the module you selected and their dependencies and no more.

Comment: Great find thanks! But can you please explain what goes inside the both the config files for selectizer? I can't find an example. @AugustoAltman

Comment: Oh yes, sorry... If you need an example you could check the repo the "example" folder: https://github.com/augusto-altman/selectizer .Also note that in the main page there is a section that explains how to use the examples in that folder. Check that out and ask me if you have any question...

Comment: Wow thank you, this is doing exactly what I was looking for! Just one last thing, after It joins all the file it puts define statments after the functions. They look like: define("css", function(){});. This is causing errors. Is there any way I can stop these from being generated?  @AugustoAltman

Comment: Mmmm... do me a favor, post it as an issue in the repo giving more details, so i can reproduce it and fix it.

https://github.com/augusto-altman/selectizer/issues ... in that link you can post issues or questions

Comment: Nevertheless I'm guessing that the problem is produced because you are defining the module like define("css", function(//bla bla bla ... try with define(["css"], function(//bla bla bla ... with the depencie inside brackets (an array of dependencies... no matter that is only one element in the array)

Comment: But this thing is I'm not trying to make a node project. Im actually tring to make a library. So I think node is somehow considering the seperate js files I am trying to merge as modules. Well thanks anyway I'll post the issue on the repo.

Comment: I don't think that nodejs is adding anything... is that's the case then, how could the examples be working?... Have you tried using define(["css"], function(//bla bla bla instead of define("css", function(//bla bla bla ... put the module's dependencies (css) in brackets notation instead of simple using a string